# PackageInfo getPackageName null in Splash screen, works in subsequent activities

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to retrieve package name below:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo  = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(),1);
```

When I do this in Splash screen, it returns `null`, but same code works well in other activities.

My manifest file contains the name and version in current format.

Comment: where you doing it in Splash Activity? inside `onCreate()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured that out, context was null.